# differentiate `to+verb` from `verb` in the context of a list

Tags: omissibility, particles

He gives wisdom and knowledge to enable his children to understand and see the invisible.

He gives wisdom and knowledge to enable his children to understand and to see the invisible.

Sometimes I come across this type of sentences and don`t understand when we should use "to" twice.

Answer (score -1):

Black Death:

To answer your question fully: English is a prescriptive language.  So, people will apply 'to' to both verbs in some situations, even if it is incorrect: in other situations, they will only apply 'to' to the second verb if you've written it in.  English is not generally a technical language so people will interpret the language based on their own grammatical style; therefore, when comprehending literature, you need to interview the author (otherwise your interpretation might be wildly incorrect).

'to' is used to indicate an external force which creates the desire, according to Quora.

My opinion is that `the action, x, in 'to x', will be continued until it is successful`.

Furthermore, I find it [quaint](/questions/tagged/quaint) to use a more developed grammar in which [to](/questions/tagged/to) takes on a special meaning and fits in unusual situations.  For example, you sometimes hear people to say: "I must to go," which is certainly to be acceptable under to the right circumstances.